# Detect when DB server goes down during JDBC query

Tags: mysql, jdbc, tcp

My application makes queries to MySQL using JDBC. Sometimes, while a query is running, connectivity will be lost to the server. Rather than detecting this and throwing an exception, the code hangs until the TCP connection finally times out (which takes over 10 minutes)

Setting a query timeout doesn't work. If the DB server stays up this will timeout queries, but does nothing if the server goes down before the timeout triggers.

Setting `socketTimeout` in the MySQL connection string or invoking `.withNetworkTimeout` on the `Connection` object sort of works. This does force the connection to timeout if no response is received after the specified timeout, however it will also kill queries that run longer than the timeout even if the DB server is up. I want to die fast if the DB server goes down but still be able to run long queries.

If I could get at the sockets Keepalive settings so I could set the interval/number of probes lower and that would solve the problem, but I can't see anyway to do that with the MySQL JDBC driver.

How can I cause queries to fail quickly when the DB server goes down, while still being able to run long queries?